# Non-summable sampling of integrable function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lp-spaces

given a continuous function $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, I can't seem to find out if $\forall a, b \in \mathbb{R_+^*}$, the sequence $(u_n := f(a + bn))_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is absolutely summable for sure or not. I don't have a lead for this, but I can't find a counter-example either.

Thanks by advance !

EDIT : I had the idea to use the fact that for any non-zero natural integer $N$, $b = \frac{a + Nb - a}{N}$, so the sum can be understood as some sort of Riemann sum over $[a, a + Nb]$ maybe possibly. Then, using the fact that $f \in L_1(\mathbb R)$, say that there exists some $N_l$ so that $f$ is "negligeable" on $[N_l, +\infty)$ in order to replace the right bound of the summation's interval with $N_l$ in order to get rid of the dependency to $N$. Not sure where to go with this, but that's what I have.

Comment: Regarding the quantifiers: you want to find if "for every $a,b$, the sequence is summable" or if "there exist some $a,b$ for which it is sommable"?

Comment: @ClementC. Didn't he specify the former?

Comment: "any" sounds a bit ambiguous to me, but that's how I'd interpret it my default. @zhw.

Comment: I'm trying to determine if the sequence is summable for every value of $a$ and $b$, yes. I'll edit to clarify

Comment: This has been asked a billion times here at MSE. Since I am never able to search well here: Visualize triangles centered over $1,2, \dots $ of heights $1$ having bases equal to $1/2^1, 1/2^2, \dots $. Define the function to be $0$ everywhere else. What do you think?

Comment: I think the "does there exist" question is interesting though, no?

Comment: @zhw. alright, I may be wrong on this, but I think such a function isn't continuous. By reversing the epsilon-delta definition of continuity (to disprove it), you just have to take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, and then for any $\delta > 0$ there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$ so that $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} < \delta$. You then take $x = n$ and $y = x - \frac{\delta + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}{2}$ ; we now have $|x - y| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(y)| = 1 > \epsilon$ because $x$ is an integer and $y$ is outside the triangle corresponding to $x$. Thus, such a function is not continuous.

Comment: No, that's totally wrong. Just start drawing triangles as I described. It's bleepin' obvious.

Comment: Where am I wrong in my reasoning ? If your function isn't continuous, I'll disregard it since in my question, I did say that the function has to be continuous. Besides, it wouldn't be the first time mathematics doesn't behave as first seemed obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider a $L^1$ function with spikes of height $1$ on the natural numbers and take $a,b=1$.

---

Explicitly (although not of height $1$ on the naturals per se), let $f:\mathbb{R}_{ \geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x)=(x-(n+1))^{2n^2}$ if $n \leq x \leq n+2$, where $n$ is even. By the glueing lemma, this is continuous. The integral is given by $\sum\limits_{n \text{ even}}\frac{2}{2n^2+1}$. Mirroring $f$, we get a function $g$ defined on the real numbers which is in $L^1$ (since its integral is $\sum\limits_{n \text{ even}} \frac{4}{2n^2+1}$). However, $f(2+2n)=1$ for every $n$, and the series $\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 1$ diverges.

Comment: This poses the same question as with the triangles example in the comments of my question. Does this remain continuous "towards infinity" ? I didn't try this time, but seeing that your "$n$th elementary function" tends towards something that is 1 for $x = 2n$ and 0 everywhere else, I think that the same kind of proof works to show that it in fact isn't continuous on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: It is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. It does not have a limit as $x \to \infty$, which are completely different things.

Comment: Or do you think that $\sin(x)$ is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, say?

Comment: No, this is not what I meant. As I said, please look at my attempt at a proof in the comments on my own question. To sum it up, the idea is that for a certain $\epsilon$ (say, 1/2), for any $\delta > 0$, we can find an $x$ that is big enough so that there exists a $y$ no further from $x$ than $\delta$, and so that $|f(x) - f(y)| > \epsilon$. This should be possible since as I said, the "$n$th elementary function" tends towards a non-continuous function ; so by making $x$ big enough, we should always be able to find such a $y$ for any $\delta$. Again, you're better off reading the actual proof.

Comment: @Matrefeytontias What your argument (although a little sketchy) shows is that the function is not uniformly continuous. It indeed isn't. But it is continuous, and this is a mere consequence of the glueing lemma, as I said. The case of zhw is the same.

Comment: Oh wow. Turns out I actually can't read (or remember), and mixed both definitions. That's entirely my bad, this is valid then.

Comment: To give some context, I was trying to verify some weird set of hypothesis to an application of the Poisson summation formula. As I expected, it turns out the paper I was reading is wrong.